# How to define range around activecell based on a criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I am building a minesweeper game and I got everything right apart from 1 thing. I am struggle to excavate blanks (from activecell) until any number value is found in every direction.

This is part of what I currently have. I tried declare offset values as variables but did not work.

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Interior.TintAndShade = 0
End If
```

How do I get every cell turn to white and expand until any value (1 to 9) is found.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a recursive problem , you need to craete a recursive function i will answer for you

I hope you can get some "Logic" about what i tried to do here ,

```
Public Sub checkUntilItsHaveNumber(ByVal c As Range)
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.Interior.TintAndShade = 0
        Call checkUntilItsHaveNumber(c.Offset(1, 0))
        Call checkUntilItsHaveNumber(c.Offset(-1,0))
        Call checkUntilItsHaveNumber(c.Offset(0, 1))
        Call checkUntilItsHaveNumber(c.Offset(0, -1))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ronan, It is helpful however I am too novice to put this together but I am still really interested. If you could give me an exact solution I would definetly learn from it.